# Run script after switching user account "to the same account"

Tags: scripts, switch-user

In Ubuntu, when I click on **Switch User Account...** and then choose the same account to log in (for example if my name is John Smith, I click on switch user account and then log into the John Smith account again), how can I run a script after that?

*(I know, that I can run a script after "**first**" login by putting it in `/etc/profile` file, but this script is not executed again when I choose switch user account and then immediately log in back to the same account.)*

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how this would behave, but you can try putting the script under ~/.bashrc, which is local to every user.

Comment: No it will not help me - ~/.bashrc file is executed when I start terminal - not when "relogin"